# Parsing XML in Android - AsyncTask

Tags: android, xml

I am a newbie in Android development. Now I am trying to parse. I have got many tutorials for parsing XML. But I would like to know parse XML asynchronously. I have found somewhere, xml can be loaded asynchronously using AsyncTask. Can anybody help me to find it out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tutorial for using AsyncTask:

http://droidapp.co.uk/?p=177

And one for parsing RSS / XML:

http://droidapp.co.uk/?p=166

You need to call your parse function in doInBackground in the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class _StackOverflowActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String yourXmlString = "<put your xml String here>"; 

        ParseXMLTask parseXMLTask = new ParseXMLTask();
        parseXMLTask.execute(yourXmlString); 
    }

    class ParseXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String yourXml = params[0]; 

            //Parse your xml here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //do something after parsing is done
        }   
    }
}
```

First, you have to extend the class AsyncTask. In my example I named it ParseXMLTask.

AsyncTask requires you to implement one method which is "doInBackground". doInBackground runs in a separate thread, put your code for parsing the xml there.

After the thread finishes, onPostExecute is called. onPostExecute runs in your main thread, you can use this if you wish to perform something after doInBackground finishes

To use ParseXMLTask, you have to instantiate it to an object. Then run the command `.execute()`. You can pass objects in `execute` similar to what I have done `parseXMLTask.execute(yourXmlString);` . You can pass as many variables as you like and be sure to handle them in `doInBackground` similar to `String yourXml = params[0];` . If you have a second variable passed in .execute say... `parseXml.execute(yourXmlString, my2ndVariable);` , handle it in doInBackground through

```
 String yourXml = params[0]; 
 String the2ndVariable = params[1];
```

When you call .execute you tell AsyncTask to run whatever code you have placed in doInBackground in a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks Mussharp. Can you give me a brief description of how this class to be used?